# Event when we back from DialogFragment to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm running Activity

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("num", num);
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
SomeActivity newFragment = SomeActivity.newInstance();
newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
newFragment.show(ft, "slideshow");
...
public class SomeActivity extends DialogFragment {
  ...
}
```

So in "SomeActivity" the user clicks the back button. I want to handle this event in the MainActivity.
I tried "onResume", "onStart", but they are not called in this situation.
How can this problem be solved?
Big thanks.

Comment: `DialogFragment` won't have `backPressed()`. You need to handle it inside `onBackPressed()` of an `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work, not tested though, Override your activity's onBackPressed and check whether your DialogFragment is showing by using the fragment tag.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("slideshow")) {
        // dialog is open, do your thing
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```